# acces a file placed in src folder on mac

Tags: java, macos, file, relative-path

I try to acces a file that i've placed on the src file using a relative path but in vain.

here is an example :

```
File file=new File("src/teledeclaration.xsd");
```

but i get the following error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/eclipse2
/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/src/teledeclaration.xsd (No such file or directory)
```

why the below path appears before the normal path that i've written "src/teledeclation.xsd"

```
/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/eclipse2/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

how should i handle this problem ?

Comment: what is the directory structure of your project, and where is your project located on disk?  I have a hard time believing that your project resides inside the Eclipse.app directory

Comment: @BenGlasser i have only one package "com.stage.service", src>com>stage>service , my class is on the service folder and i try to call the "teledeclaration" file that is placed directly on src 
and my project is located in [/Users/macbookpro/Documents/workspace/]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a full path, the path will be *relative* to your current working directory. If you check `System.getProperty("user.dir")` it should point to the `Eclipse.app/...` folder.

Comment: after checking i get this path [ /Users/macbookpro/Documents/workspace/myproject ]